Shell script: Not getting value of command evaluated in variable
  path3="a/b/c"
  command="ls -1q ${!path3}* | wc -l "
  length="$(command)"
  echo $length

I am trying to move to folder assigned to variable path3, I am not getting any value of length when executing this code. What is the issue in my code?
I am expecting some value for length variable

What do you think ${!path3} does? Also, $(command) and $($command) are not the same thing.

Btw: command is a shell builtin. See help command.

@choroba ${!path3} is used to get the value of path3

@PrashantKumarJha: It's not. ${path3} or $path3 is.

Don't store commands in variables (the command="ls ... part). Variables are for storing data, functions are for storing commands. Either use a function, or don't store it at all, just execute it normally, like length="$(ls .... See BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!" and many many previous questions from people who tried this and ran into trouble.

command by itself is a no-op. Since it doesn't do anything, it does not provide any output. Therefore length=$(command) sets "length" to an empty value.

When you want to count files including subdirs, use find . -type f -exec printf "."  \; | wc -c. With the printf a file with newlines will only count once. You can modify the find, like only the current dir with find . -maxdepth 1 -exec printf "."  \;  | wc -c. The find will also count the hidden files. With ls -a you will also have .. and ..

The simplest way would be
length=$(ls -1q "$path3"/* | wc -l)

Storing the command in a variable is fragile: it will break if the $path3 contains whitespace. But if you insist, you still need the dollar sign before the variable name, otherwise the shell interprets it as a command (and command is a shell builtin in bash).
length=$($command)  # Not recommended.

If you need to store code for reuse, use a function, not a variable.
The exclamation mark syntax is used for variable indirection: The ${!path3} would work if $path3 contained a variable name whose value you'd be interested in. To get a variable's value, just use ${variable} or even $variable.

when running the command :
command1="ls -1q $path3* | wc -l "
echo $command1
,
I am getting output: ls -1q  followed by folder names in the current dir recursively and then | wc -l , why is it so?
@choroba

@PrashantKumarJha: That's because of variable and path expansions. Read about expansions in man bash. Also, I doubt the "recursively" part.

@PrashantKumarJha as mentioned in an earlier comment - do not store code in variables, store code in functions. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.
